# Xcode 7.2 does not allow me to create an ipa file for ad hoc distribution -> An App record has not been found

Tags: ios, xcode

Xcode 7.2 creating ipa file for ad hoc distribution -> Cannot archive and get this message: Missing App Version A matching version for "1.0" build "1" was not found

Comment: Are you sure you're exporting for Ad-Hoc Distribution? Because the error you mention sounds a lot like an error related to the App Store

Comment: Tom, I appreciate your comments but... yes, this is not the first App I create/archive. Unfortunately when I come across with these situations I do not seem to find quick solutions. Just a little frustrated. Hopefully someone else has seen this before.

Comment: I'm getting the same error when I try to download the dsym from the organizer. "An app record for “**.**” was found but a matching version for “1.0.3” build “10” was not."